# Rserve: Connection Refused: Connect

Tags: java, r, exception, rserve

I am trying to execute a R script from my Java code.
This is the java code I have

```
package pkg;

import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;

public class Temp {
public static void main(String a[]) {
    RConnection connection = null;

    try {
        /* Create a connection to Rserve instance running on default port
         * 6311
         */
        connection = new RConnection();

        connection.eval("source('D:\\\\r script\\\\TestRserve.R')");
        connection.eval("Rserve()");
        int num1=10;
        int num2=20;
        int sum=connection.eval("myAdd("+num1+","+num2+")").asInteger();
        System.out.println("The sum is=" + sum);
    } catch (RserveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The TestRserve.R is as follows

```
  library(Rserve)
  Rserve()
  x= matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
  plot.ts(x)
```

I have used a sample code from a tutorial and AFAIK, the TestRserve is not being executed in the Java file. I have also tried something like below to execute the TestRserve.R

```
        REXP x;
        System.out.println("Reading script...");
        File file = new File("D:\\r script\\TestRserve.R");
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                System.out.println(line);
                x = c.eval(line);         // evaluates line in R
                System.out.println(x);    // prints result
            }
        }
```

The following is the stack trace

> Exception in thread "main" org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: Cannot connect: Connection refused: connect
>       at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.(RConnection.java:88)
>       at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.(RConnection.java:60)
>       at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.(RConnection.java:44)
>       at functionTest.HelloWorldApp.main(HelloWorldApp.java:17)

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of misconceptions about Rserve that are discernible from your code.

First of all, Rserve is a server and the Rserve JAR files provide the client implementations to interact with Rserve, just like there are JavaScript clients on `npm`.

Thus to call R scripts through Rserve, Rserve server needs to be already started and waiting to receive calls. This can be done from R using:

```
library(Rserve)
Rserve()
```

or,:
`R CMD Rserve --vanilla` directly from linux bash
or,calling it directly from Java using JavaRuntime API to access the runtime:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("R CMD RServe --vanilla");
```

although this also works for linux only.

Then you should execute your Java  client code to connect to the Rserve server and `eval()` all your R commands through Rserve.